# imap-simple with proxy does not work nodejs

Tags: node.js, imap

I am trying to use imap-simple with socks5 proxy, but it does not work. I tried with port 993 tls true, 993 tls false, 143 tls true, 143 tls false.

That's my code

```
await imaps.connect({
            imap: {
                user: "mail@bla.com",
                password: "xyzxyz",
                
                host: imapInfo.HOST,
                port: imapInfo.PORT,
                tls: imapInfo.TLS,

                proxy: {
                    host: "127.0.0.1",
                    port: parseInt("12345"),
                    type: 5,
                    userId: "bla@bla.com",
                    password: "bla"
                },

                tlsOptions: {
                    rejectUnauthorized: false
                }
            }
        }).then(connection => {
        
        }).catch(err => {
            console.error(err);
        });
```

and that's the error message:

```
Socks5 proxy rejected connection - NotAllowed
```

so I don't understand what the problem is. Im searching for solutions.